# How to static link SpiderMonkey

Tags: c++, mozilla, static-linking, spidermonkey

I built SpiderMonkey v60 (the Firefox Javascript Engine) release like in the [official documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Build_Documentation#Building_SpiderMonkey_as_a_static_library) as a static library (I am trying to avoid dlls). After I added the import files and the js_static.lib to Visual Studio, linking errors occured.

I defined STATIC_JS_API (which should mean that mozilla should compile with the static library), but the only thing happened was the errors got more. I also tried to build SpiderMonkey differently and used mozjs-60.lib to it but nothing changed.

After adding STATIC_JS_API, I had compiling errors like "unresolved extern symbol _imp_timeBeginPeriod@4", "unresolved extern symbol _imp_timeEndPeriod@4", "unresolved symbol _imp_PR_GetOpenFileInfo" (altogether 7 unresolved symbols). I am using the [hello world code from mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/How_to_embed_the_JavaScript_engine) for SpiderMonkey 52, so this should be no problem, also the full building ran off without an error.

Comment: Try and see where these symbols (e.g. `_imp_timeBeginPeriod@4`) are, which `lib` or `dll` and see that you link against these. You can use dependency walker from `http://www.dependencywalker.com/` to find these symbols.

Comment: Did you fix it? Cuz I have the same issue. I built the same version, but how did you get the ```mozjs-60.lib```? I only got the ```js_static.lib```